# SQL: How to perform this query over each group

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 and I have the following setup. I have a table which is organised as follows:

```
ID   k  count
1    a     1 
1    b     2
1    c     5
2    a     3
2    b     4
3    a     2
```

What I want to do is compute the element wise product-sum between the count column for each ID where they share a k.

So, for example, between 1 and 2, the element wise sum is `SUM (1*3 + 2*4)` as they share the `a` and `b` key. Similarly, between 2 and 3, it will be `SUM(3*2)` as they only share the 'a' key.

It is because I have to create this for every ID pair i.e. `(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)`, I am not sure how to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` to find all matching pairs:

```
SELECT t1.ID AS t1ID, t2.ID AS t2ID, 
       SUM(t1.count*t2.count) AS s
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 
  ON t1.ID < t2.ID AND t1.k = t2.k
GROUP BY t1.ID, t2.ID
```

Using `GROUP BY t1.ID, t2.ID` we can easily calculate element wise sum for each pair.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/99e57/2)

Comment: Ok, I forgot this group by expression will do the sub-column selection!

Answer (score 0):

@Luca instead of Generating as pairs((1,2),(2,3),(1,3)) ,you can generate as(1,2,3...) .You can use subquery inorder to find the appropriate condition and produce the desired output.